# "Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I am using the following code to set session headers in response in Lambda Edge. But i always get this error.

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined",
        "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:118:30)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}
```

Code I am using is this

```
exports.handler = function (event, config, callback) {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    console.log(event.Records[0].cf);
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const headers = response.headers;

    getConfigCached(request, function (err, config) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }
        else if (request.uri !== "/code" && !redirectIfNotAuthenticated(config, request, callback)) {
            callback(null, request);
        }
        else if (request.uri == "/code") {
            console.log('INSIDE CODE');
            let access_token = accessTokenCallback(request, callback);
            console.log(access_token);
            headers['session-token'] = [{ key: 'Session-Token', value: access_token }];
            callback(null, response);
        }
    });
};
```

CloudFront trigger is set to viewer request

Comment: Obviously `event.Records[0].cf.response` is `undefined`. What's the question?

Comment: Why is it undefined ? Do I need to change the trigger to Viewer Response ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the setting you configured your Lambda@Edge when you created it.
It's supposed to be set to `Response origin` for you to be able to set the response headers.

BTW there is a blueprint for creating this kind of Lambda@edge
[AWS Blueprint](https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-east-1#/create/function/configure/blueprint?blueprint=cloudfront-modify-response-header)

Comment: Thanks, but can you indicate where to set this `Response origin` with more details.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a Trigger you can set to attach to the Origin Response. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-add-triggers.html